Encryption dilemas in my workflow in a Flutter app
I'm building an app in Flutter that needs to keep sensitive information very safe and I'm using Supabase to keep my clients information on the cloud. I know Supabase has the vault, but there is no examples in how to use it to encrypt/decrypt table columns. I also wants that if my bussiness grows, I don't want any employee or even me to be able to read user's personal information, so I guess we won't be using vault. So, encryption/decryption will be done by the client side.
I know almost nothing about encryption, so pardon me for any obvious errors.
The ideia is to have an encrypted passkey by the user password. So, if a user changes the password, I just encrypt the original passkey again and store that in the supabase and the sqlite. Of course, I will add certain requirements for the password, like upper and lower case letters, special characters, etc. This way, I assume, even if a employee have admin access to our database, they cannot read the user data.
I can do the decryption of the passkey only when it's needed, so it may not be lying on memory when not needed. But how to story the actual password to do the decryption of the passkey? I just put it in some variable and leave it there?
This is designed with symmetric encryption key in mind. Do you guys think asymmetric is better? Is there any security holes in this? Do you have any sugestions? Do you recommend another place I can go to get better advice? What encryption libraty for Flutter/Dart do you recommend? Thank you!


Security  is all in details and implementation, so it isnt possible for an overview of a design to end with "that's secure." But the basic model of "user-provided password encrypts random key" is the typical practice. All arbitrary-length encryption is symmetric. Asymmetric encryption is generally used just to encrypt random symmetric keys. It's not practical (or desirable) to encrypt entire files with asymmetric algorithms. As long as the encryption and decryption is done entirely on the client-side, and the server just stored encrypted data and no keys, then your basic plan is sensible.

@RobNapier Thanks for your input, but my encrypted passkey needs to be in the postgree server, right? If a user logs in another device, he must be able to decrypt the data with his password.

You would send the encrypted key to the user and they would decrypt it with their password. Yes, this can create challenges around password resets when the user forgets their password. It is all a very challenging problem, full of trade-offs. There's no Stackoverflow-style answer or assessment. It depends heavily on your specific use case, user and data profiles, attacker profiles, and all the other details. If this is critical to your business, you will want to hire a security engineer to design something that matches your needs.

@RobNapier Thanks so much. Your input was very helpul!
